# Google Adsense does not find the code on my blogger

Tags: html, blogger, adsense

I have a problem with my blogger, when I try to link my Google Adsense account it shows me that it does not find the code, and sometimes it does not find the site, The problem is that I do not understand much about these things, it looks to me like a dark room, I was told that the problem is in HTML, But I didn't understand it ,Also when i add a new topic it disappears and does not appear on the home page, or the place allocated to it, even though I put it label, I was wondering if I copied and sent my HTML blogger, can ony one help me? Thank you

Comment: What did you tried?

Comment: Where did you try to add the code? If possible, add a link to your blog so that people can check.

Comment: i Copied the code and Paste it into the HTML of my site under  <head> , tthis is my site link  http://www.thbofficial.com

Comment: adsense ad code is present in your theme, and it is ok. There must be some issue with adsense interconnecting to your site.

Answer (score 2):

There are different ways of adding AdSense to your Blogger blog. There is some explanation at http://www.google.com/support/blogger/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=42281

For more information:

1. http://helpfulinformationfornewbies.blogspot.com/2009/09/getting-started-with-adsense-and.html
2. http://helpfulinformationfornewbies.blogspot.com/2010/02/editing-html-in-blogger-template.html

Answer (score 1):

If you are trying to get your site approved with Adsense, then you must first get it approved on a naked domain (i.e., http://thbofficial.com, rather than on http://www.thbofficial.com.

Google looks for the ad code on the naked version of the domain, perhaps to make sure you own the domain.